# Floating Point Comparison C++ - Finding maximum

Tags: c++

When I do floating point comparison I am getting **inf** printed in the output screen. Can anyone please help?

```
unsigned long long temp;
long double tempDec=0.0,max=0.0;
unsigned long long maxInd=0,j=0;

for(unsigned long long i=1;i<100;i++)
{
    j=i-1;
    temp=0;
    while(j>0)
    {
        if(returnGCD(j,i)==1)
        {
            temp++;
        }
        j--;
    }


    tempDec = ((long double)i)/((long double)temp);

    if(tempDec>max)
    {
        max=tempDec;
        maxInd=i;
    }
}

cout << max << " # " << maxInd << endl;
```

When I tried out this snippet, I am getting the output as

```
inf # 1
```

I don't know whats wrong with it. Only for an equal comparison we can use fabs(), is there any other special way to find out the greater number in float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first iteration of the loop, `temp=0`, `j=0` making `tempDec` to be infinite because of division by 0. `if(tempDec>max)` will be true first time and sets `max` to infinity. From there onwards, that `if` will always be false.

Fix the code so you don't divide by 0.